# how to just use basic groovy script in gradle?

Tags: gradle

So, I have the following which seems to be working as desired right now

```
task deleteJars(type: Delete) {
    ext.collection = files { genLibDir.listFiles() }
    delete ext.collection
}

task copyJars(type: Copy) { 
    from(configurations.compile) {}
    from(fixedLibDir) {}
    into genLibDir
}

copyJars.dependsOn('deleteJars')
```

I have a few questions

1. Is there a cleaner way of writing that into one function the gradle way?
2. Previously, I had the below but it seems the copy functions would be executed always instead of when the copyJars task ran?
3. How do you write simple groovy(for example delete a file, copy a file, etc. etc.) in a task so when the task is depended on, it runs correct?

My horrible try at having groovy run when the task is depended on(but unfortunately ran no matter what target I picked and ran every single run)...

```
task('copyJars') { 
    ext.collection = files { genLibDir.listFiles() }
    delete ext.collection
    copy { from configurations.compile into genLibDir }
    copy { from fixedLibDir into genLibDir }
}
```

so my main question is how do you write groovy script in a task so it only runs when that task runs?  (as I thought the above was groovy script but it seems to run every single time)

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Gradle build proceeds in three phases: initialization, configuration, and execution. Most code in a build script gets evaluated in the configuration phase, which is independent of which tasks will eventually get run. (The decision which tasks to run is only made at the very end of the configuration phase, once all tasks and their dependencies are known.) To add code that gets run if and when a task executes (i.e. in the execution phase), you use `doFirst` or `doLast` to add a so-called *task action* to the task. For example:

```
task copyJars {
    doLast { /* put any Groovy code here */ }
}
```

You can learn more about these concepts in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Answer (score 0):

okay, so using that, this did work(had to take out the type of task though or it would not run)

```
task copyJars() {
    doLast {
        ext.collection = files { genLibDir.listFiles() }
        delete ext.collection
        copy { from configurations.compile into genLibDir }
        copy { from fixedLibDir into genLibDir }
    }
}
```